# click event of a button that contains more buttons, fires events wrong

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, button, click

I´m facing this problem:
I have a Button that works like a WrapPanel using the property "Template"

```
Template="{StaticResource WrapLikeTemplate}"
```

Where "WrapLikeTemplate is as follows:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="WrapLikeTemplate">            
            <WrapPanel Name="wpBody" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,0,0">                   
                <Button Content="{Binding XPath=./BUTTONS/Button[1]/Text}" Click="b1_Click" Height="55" Name="b1" Width="157" Margin="65,10" />
                <Button Content="{Binding XPath=./BUTTONS/Button[2]/Text}" Click="b2_Click" Height="55" Name="b2" Width="157" Margin="65,10" />
                <Button Content="{Binding XPath=./BUTTONS/Button[3]/Text}" Click="b3_Click" Height="55" Name="b3" Width="157" Margin="65,10" />
                <Button Content="{Binding XPath=./BUTTONS/Button[4]/Text}" Click="b4_Click" Height="55" Name="b4" Width="157" Margin="65,10" />
                <Button Content="{Binding XPath=./BUTTONS/Button[5]/Text}" Click="b5_Click" Height="55" Name="b5" Width="157" Margin="65,10" />
                <Button Content="{Binding XPath=./BUTTONS/Button[6]/Text}" Click="b6_Click" Height="55" Name="b6" Width="157" Margin="65,10" />
                <Button Content="{Binding XPath=./BUTTONS/Button[7]/Text}" Click="b7_Click" Height="55" Name="b7" Width="157" Margin="65,10" />
                <Button Content="{Binding XPath=./BUTTONS/Button[8]/Text}" Click="b8_Click" Height="55" Name="b8" Width="157" Margin="65,10" />
                <Button Content="{Binding XPath=./BUTTONS/Button[9]/Text}" Click="b9_Click" Height="55" Name="b9" Width="157" Margin="65,10" />
                <Button Content="{Binding XPath=./BUTTONS/Button[10]/Text}" Click="b10_Click" Height="55" Name="b10" Width="157" Margin="65,10" />                    
            </WrapPanel>            
    </ControlTemplate>
```

So, if i click on a Button, it fires its click event first, and then the click event of its parent; i mean the button that contains it (the one with the WrapPanel Template).

What i need is that when a button is pressed, to execute the click event of it, and just this, NOT the click event of its parent.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the event handler:

```
private void b1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

should work.

EDIT: I tried it. It works.